# Cold-emailing researcher from same country

Tags: email, networking

I am a PhD student in the final year of my PhD who has been struggling with creating new connections in my field, especially due to the current Covid situation. Conferences are only taking place online and nobody of relevance really sticks around for longer than their own talks. Also, my advisor unfortunately does not have that many contacts in my field to begin with.

Recently, I found out there is another researcher in the same field as me, some years my senior, and who comes from the same country as me (Brazil). As it so happens, we are I suppose the only two people from there who currently work on this field (but I am sure he is not aware of my "existence" just yet).

Since I also find his research interesting, I thought about cold-emailing him with some form of collaboration or even a postdoc in mind. There is already a myriad of advice on this site in that sense, of course; I was wondering how the common background may affect the best strategy to do so. Perhaps I could use it to make my email stand out from the rest? Still, my fear is that this might be seen as "lame" and that I might end up being perceived as only looking for "favors" on the basis of being from the same country as him.

**Question:** Can I somehow use the common background to my advantage? Or do I risk shooting myself in the foot by doing so? Or am I just overthinking all of this and the main focus should be on the research anyway (where the common background is nothing but a nice triviality)?

Comment: What is it exactly that you want to get out of contacting this person?

Comment: @henning Edited question a bit to reflect that.

Comment: What does your adviser say? Maybe your adviser could send a brief e-mail before, saying something like "I have this great student who's also in Brazil, working on blah blah and is very interested in your work. My student has been trying to reach out to more senior researchers. Would you be willing to chat with my student?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think if you *use a common background to build rapport* you're good to go. There's no guarantee it'll increase your chances of a response, but it might pique a little interest. I see no harm in it. I'd expect it might be more effective if you had come from a smaller country (or restricted region in a larger one), but in a narrow enough field it might be notable enough.

If you think of it as an *expectation for assistance* then you're on shakier ground, and the insinuation is even likely to offend someone. It seems you've already got this concern covered, though, so I think that will prevent you from saying anything too off-putting.

Cold emails are generally low-success ventures, but there are lots of advice Q&A on this stack about them. Be brief and direct, don't be overly persistent or upset if you don't get a response. The shared background can be added as a brief half-sentence to one-sentence note. You ask:

> Or am I just overthinking all of this and the main focus should be on the research anyway (where the common background is nothing but a nice triviality)?

Yes, I think that's the best way to phrase it - the background is a nice triviality. But sometimes social and professional relationships can build from trivialities, especially shared experience. Have a focused research/science goal for your message, not just "Hi I am also from Brazil!" Think more specifically about what your goals are, like @henning asked in a comment. Even "collaboration or postdoc" may be too broad/vague.

Comment: Second paragraph, especially, is excellent.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to email him simply to establish an open-ended connection, I don't know how likely it is that you'll get a reply. If you're interested in doing some research under him, consider if you will be able to spare the time to do so, given that you're already pursuing a PhD. Maybe keep your advisor in the loop about all this, though I am not sure how he/she will perceive this.

If you DO want to conduct research under the other researcher and don't see any problems, then yeah, by all means, go ahead and email him. I think you can be honest about your reasons for emailing him: that networking with researchers from other countries has gotten much more difficult due to Covid-19, that you are interested in his research and that the common background makes this a more attractive proposition to you in general. Maybe mention what exactly you intend to accomplish working with him.

I don't think mentioning the common background will be a disadvantage by any means. I certainly don't think that it will be seen as "lame". I also don't see why he would think you're looking only for favors, as long as you talk primarily about his research and your work in the same field. You will not be shooting yourself in the foot. Ideally the main focus WILL be on the research, and the common background will be nothing but a nice triviality.